# Pytorch LSTM - initializing hidden states during training

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a Class that contains my LSTM Model and I have a training loop over some Data (=trajectories of a pendulum).
When I train the model I have to initialize the hidden state for each timestep. Which confuses me since I thought the power of the LSTM (RNN) would be, that i use the previous hidden state for the next calculation... but I set it to zeros every time. Also the model works very well for predicting the pendulum.
(This code is "heavily inspired" from an article that uses it on a really similar problem)

This is the Model Class:

```
class LSTMmodel(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size_1,hidden_size_2,out_size):
        
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_size_1 = hidden_size_1
        self.hidden_size_2 = hidden_size_2
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.lstm_1 = nn.LSTM(input_size,hidden_size_1)
        self.lstm_2 = nn.LSTM(hidden_size_1,hidden_size_2)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size_2,out_size)
        self.hidden_1 = (
            torch.zeros(1,1,hidden_size_1),
            torch.zeros(1,1,hidden_size_1)
        )
        self.hidden_2 = (
            torch.zeros(1,1,hidden_size_2),
            torch.zeros(1,1,hidden_size_2)
        )
        
    def forward(self,seq):
        lstm_out_1 , self.hidden_1 = self.lstm_1(seq.view(-1,1,self.input_size),self.hidden_1) 
        lstm_out_2 , self.hidden_2 = self.lstm_2(lstm_out_1,self.hidden_2)  
        pred = self.linear(lstm_out_2.view(len(seq),-1))
        return pred
```

This is the training loop:

```
def train(model, ddt):

    loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.001)

    model.train()
        # Set the number of epochs
    epochs = 50

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        
        # Running each batch separately 
        
        for bat in range(0,len(training_data), data[0].size(dim=0)):#
            #model.hidden_1 = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_1), torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_1))
            #model.hidden_2 = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_2), torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_2))
        
            for seq,label in training_data[bat:bat+data[0].size(dim=0)]:
                model.hidden_1 = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_1),                 torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_1))
                model.hidden_2 = (torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_2), torch.zeros(1,1,model.hidden_size_2))
        
                seq=seq.to(device)
                label=label.to(device)

                # set the optimization gradient to zero
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                model.zero_grad()
                # initialize the hidden states
                
                # Make predictions on the current sequence
                if ddt: 
                    y_pred = model(seq) + seq # learn derivative?
                else:
                    y_pred = model(seq)

                # Compute the loss
                loss = loss_fn(y_pred, label)         
                # Perform back propogation and gradient descent

                loss.backward(retain_graph=True)

                optimizer.step()
```

The Model should simply predict the pendulums angle at the next timestep given its current position.

If I try to only initialize the hidden states at the start of each batch (commented out) I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

Trying to set
`loss.backward(retain_graph=True)`
does not solve the issue. I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.DoubleTensor [15, 40]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 7206; expected version 7205 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

I assume this is because the some Tensor inside the model is changed after the gradient update?
Any suggestions on how to fix this would be great!

I am a bit confused since I thought the point of LSTMs (and RNNs) in general is to retain the hidden state and use it in the next timestep.. But now I set the hidden state to 0 and it still works pretty good.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-init the hidden state for each batch. In terms of using the previous hidden state, your batch input should be multiple timesteps. The input to `nn.LSTM` is of shape `(sl, bs, d_in)` (or `(bs, sl, d_in)` if `batch_first=True`). `sl` denotes the number of timesteps in the batch. You re-init the hidden state for each batch, but each batch has multiple timesteps. Each timestep in the batch uses the hidden state from the previous timestep. This all happens within `nn.LSTM`.

You want something like this:

```py
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, d_hidden, num_layers, output_size):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.d_hidden = d_hidden
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        
        # I find `batch_first=True` is easier to work with
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, d_hidden, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(d_hidden, output_size)
        
    def forward(self, x, hidden=None):
        
        if hidden is None:
            hidden = self.get_hidden(x)
            
        x, hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x, hidden
    
    def get_hidden(self, x):
        # note the second axis is batch size, which is `x.shape[0]` for `batch_first=True`
        hidden = (
                torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.shape[0], self.d_hidden, device=x.device),
                torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.shape[0], self.d_hidden, device=x.device),
                )
        return hidden
```

The reason to return both the output and the hidden state is to re-use the hidden state for inference. Inference would look something like this:

```py
input_value = ... # some initial input
hidden = None
prediction_steps = 5 # number of timesteps to predict 
preds = []

with torch.no_grad():
    for i in range(prediction_steps):
        # output + hidden are inputs for the next timestep
        input_value, hidden = model(input_value, hidden)
        preds.append(input_value)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! To clarify:
If my data is solutions to a differential equation. One Batch is one Solution x(t) for t=0...10
And I pass the whole Batch to the nn.LSTM() so the input is (1, 2, 10) 
I iterate over the batches in training and reset the hidden states at the start of each batch?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reset those layers during training. Your goal is to train those layers! You seem to be re-assigning the entire layer as well hence the memory errors. You should initialize those layers at model creation.

Also, you want to initialize layers to random values, I'm not sure a case where initializing to 0 is good.

Check out this doc: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html